# How to automatically enforce a formula in cells for a newly created row?

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have a worksheet used for estimation where some columns have a formula, most importantly Column(A) has a formula =ROW() which I used as an ID for that estimate (row item) and Column(I) is a total (=SUM(E2:H2)) of all the estimates in that row.

When a user inserts a new row (a new estimate) I need to ensure the new row already have the required formulas in them, I do not want to have the user need to drag the formula from the cells above it (this is not being used by Excel-savy people).

Also, this should only be done to a specific range of rows (I do not want to see an ID/Total for Row750 if it is not used), there needs to be a way to tell it to stop at a specific point (for example I have a row(13) there B13="TOTAL" and C13=SUM of totals (overall total) and this should be the last row, so if the user interests a new row it would be above this one, etc...

Any help/hints/ideas would be much appreciated.

Comment: You need a row added event: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/showthread.php?80626-Insert-Row-quot-Event-quot

Comment: If you use ROW() as an ID, wont all your ID's change if someone inserts a new row near the top of the table?

Comment: Yes ... do you have a better idea on how to add unique IDs?

Comment: I don't know of a solution to your Id issue which doesn't involve some VBA.  You would probably be best off adding a button to create new rows - you then can populate the Id (along with the formulas) as you wish.  For example, you can use a cell (or a defined name) to hold the "next" Id, and increment it each time you create a new row.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the 'Tables' feature. In Excel 2003 it was called 'Lists'. I'm not sure where to find this feature in 2010.

Ex:

Define a range as being a <del>list</del> table. I used the `ROW()` function to autonumber the rows. Here's how it looks:

[image: data list]

It doesn't overcome the problem that [Tim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11672010/how-to-automatically-enforce-a-formula-in-cells-for-a-newly-created-row#comment15473471_11672010) mentioned, but I file that under "not a problem". I actually prefer dynamic autonumbering. When you insert a row, the autonumber changes automatically:

[image: insert row in list]

And when you delete a row, the autonumber adjusts:

[image: delete row in list]

The best part is that any formulas in the <del>list</del> table will auto-fill down. Besides the `ROW` formula, I added a `SUM` formula in column C, then added a new record:

[image: list fill down formula]

As far as stopping at some point, you will need to move your formulas to another column. The list will continue down and won't stop simply because you have a formula there. You would need to right-click the <del>list</del> table, choose "Insert » Row" in order to keep your formulas in the same columns as the <del>list</del> table.